# JS seems to stay in DOM on Ajax reloaded pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reload, stack

OK this is an odd error, as it's the first ajax page without any complete reloads I'm creating it's an error I never had to face before... and even the Internet doesn't help me - as it doesn't seem to be an usual problem.

Let's get to the Problem step by step:
I have a page where the Ajax request is triggered by a function which simplified looks like this:

```
$("a[rel='tab']").live('click',function(e) {

pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
  $('#content').html(data);
}});
if(pageurl!=window.location){
  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
}
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

This is parsed by the PHP File and if the property is set the design won't be loaded but instead just the file itself gets loaded - easy hu?

OK, now the problem itself - it was obvious that the page became slower with the time but I didn't really bother at first as I thought it was some mistake in the designs javascripts - but it wasn't.

So I took a look at the firebug and what I've seen explained a lot -> The Requests stack up with every new page! Of course that would lead into an overkill... Well at first I thought it were just the "setInterval"'s and got a workaround running which resets them on each reload.

But that wasn't the only case they also seem to stack up in "scripts" as I don't think that's a plain history as just the reloaded scripts show up more than once!

Any hints in the right would be really helpfull as I am pretty much stuck here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK as it seems the issue is just related to the setInterval after all - After trying around for a while I came to the conclusion that this was the main problem, and it was just some kind of a loop in firebug itself.

However maybe someone gets stuck on the same issue so the solution is pretty much this way:
You have to:
1. Create an array where to store your Intervals
2. call your setIntervals this way
3. Reset them on each "new window"

```
var intervalArr = new Array();

function killIntervals(){
while(intervalArr.length > 0)
    clearInterval(intervalArr.pop());
};
```

These  are the array and the function

So these should be added in your AJAX Request function:

```
killIntervals();
intervalArr.push(setInterval (yourintervalfunction, 5000));
```

I hope this will come in handy for someone.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `setInterval` in your original code? Are you periodically calling the Ajax function? Normally you should avoid using `setInterval` with Ajax, since you never know when the request will finish. Use `setTimeout` instead and call it in the  success callback. This way, you only ever have one timeout running.

Comment: That's not a big problem if you set a var to block it until success -> as for example var blockit = false -> function called blockit = true -> on success blockit = false - there you can avoid the unneccesary calls and use setInterval without any problems :).